# Использование gem 'sanitize' в Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Хочу очистить пользовательский ввод.

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

 get '/' do
   params = sanitize_params params
   ...
 end
...
private
  def sanitize_params(params)
    Sanitize.fragment params[:url], Sanitize::Config::RESTRICTED
    params
  end
end
```

При вызове функции получаю `NoMethodError undefined method [] for nilClass` как будто `params` не передается в функцию `sanitize_params`.

Подскажите в целом как будет правильнее реализовать такое.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

  get '/' do
    sanitize_params
  end

  private

  def sanitize_params
    Sanitize.fragment params[:url], Sanitize::Config::RESTRICTED
  end
end
```